# Combat lethality

Tags: combat, trail-of-cthulhu

Thematically, and with the game's focus, combat in *Trail of Cthulhu* is supposed to be bad news for players. But if I look at the actual mechanics, I can't see the supposed lethality.

As a crude example, it is very common to see a health rating of 10 for pre-generated characters even for purist adventures. If that character is shot with a pump action shotgun from point blank range (a damage of *1d6+3*), the most *Health* they can lose is 9, which means they'd not only survive, but even stay conscious for the turn!

Is this a correct reading of the rules? Is this intended?

Comment: So to be clear... You are complaining that toc has characters that can die in one shot gun blast and a punch is not "lethal enough"?

Comment: I skimmed the rules and found an optional rule saying firearm damage that reduces a PC to 0HP instantly reduces them to -6hp. that doesn't answer the question, but it is perhaps worth mentioning here

Comment: Unfamiliar with the system, but the traditional answer for these kinds of questions in many RPGs ("how can PCs take damage that would kill anybody and still fight") is to include things like your armor, stamina and luck in the broader "health rating"/"HP pool". Getting taken down to half HP means that your reactions are getting slower, not necessarily that you've lost half the blood in your body. So if I'm GMing, I'd probably say that the first shotgun blast goes wide or catches a shoulder, and the next one (the one that actually takes a character to 0 health) strikes true.

Comment: @Kaia: but my question here is about NOT wanting characters (either PCs *or NPCs*) to be able to take too much damage, about wanting them to be fragile, for thematic reasons

Comment: @Questor: Not even. Purely numerically, gunshot blast + punch will get them below 0 Health, but nowhere near death at -12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Trail of Cthulhu is Gumshoe!

[Trail of Cthulhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail_of_Cthulhu) uses the [Gumshoe engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumshoe_System), and indeed, if properly built, it is not instantly lethal by virtue of the engine - not the game itself. That was a deliberate choice of the Gumshoe designers. While lethality *might* be increased, it is not part of the main design goals of Gumshoe to offer such a deadly game. As far as I can tell, no Gumshoe game has any weapon that is able to inflict the required damage to get any character to -12 instantly from full health, and as OP found out, even getting to 0 is quite hard in a single attack. That's a quirk of Gumshoe. Combat is not the main goal of a gumshoe game anyway. It's an investigation and mystery game, not a combat simulator.

### Trail of Cthulhu is less lethal... compared to Call of Cthulhu

The somewhat lower lethality in part separates it from Chaosium's [Call of Cthulhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Cthulhu_(role-playing_game)), which arguably is not just more lethal, but also puts a harder timer on every character:

- Health in Call of Cthulhu can't be regained as easily, and only over longer timeframes. In Trail of Cthulhu, that's quite easier.
- Stability is nigh impossible to be regained in Call of Cthulhu. This is also true for a Purist Trail of Cthulhu game, but Pulp games gives it back to you easier.

Among other things, [back in 2008](http://ogrecave.com/reviews/trail_cthulhu.shtml), when it first published, the comparison between the two made by ogrecave was this:

> #### Comparisons to Call of Cthulhu
>
> Many readers will undoubtedly be familiar with Chaosium's Call of Cthulhu RPG, and will be wondering how the two games stack up. First, the ways that the characters are described are somewhat different. There is some overlap in character occupations, but many of the interpersonal skills are different between the games. Also, Trail of Cthulhu has no traditional RPG attribute scores (like "Strength", "Intellect", etc.). Instead, Trail of Cthulhu is focused almost entirely on more specific skills or abilities.
>
> As for the mechanics of the two games, I prefer the GUMSHOE system over Chaosium's "Basic Roleplaying" (BRP) system. GUMSHOE's resource driven mechanics put more power in the hands of the players. Players have a greater control over when during the investigation their characters will stand out, and when they'll have to take a back seat to others. That said, GUMSHOE's investigative abilities really end up merely pointing out who gets story credit for various actions. Because core clues are automatically found by any character with an applicable Investigative Ability, in many (but certainly not all) circumstances, a rank of 1 in an Investigative Ability is just as good as 10 ranks of it.  Further, since some investigator in the group will usually have at least one rank in each core Investigative Ability, which character gets to take credit for finding the core clues of an investigation is typically determined by which character has the highest rating in an applicable Investigative Ability during a given scene.  In contrast, in a Call of Cthulhu game, the most clever player may be the one that thinks up the way to find the major clues in a given mystery, and his character may get the credit for the find.
>
> If you play the d20 version of Call of Cthulhu, expect Trail to be a lighter game with fewer specifically quantified feats to detail your character's capabilities in combat.
>
> While I prefer GUMSHOE's core mechanics, Chaosium has an absolutely fantastic wealth of source materials for Call of Cthulhu. Undoubtedly many people who buy Pelgrane's Trail of Cthulhu will be Call of Cthulhu fans, so thankfully, Trail of Cthulhu contains GUMSHOE-to-BRP conversions. This is great for GMs with loads of older Chaosium products on their shelves that prefer GUMSHOE's mechanical structure. However, some of the conversions were onerous enough that I really think Pelgrane Press and Chaosium should get together and create a conversion spreadsheet, and should give fans a limited license to just post stat block conversions between the games on the Pelgrane or Chaosium websites. Otherwise, players may convert their investigative characters using this methodology, but other source material may be too painful for GMs to convert.